# Spring Boot load time weaving doesn't work in embedded tomcat

Tags: spring-boot, aspectj, load-time-weaving, embedded-tomcat-8

I can't get LTW to work in Spring Boot 1.2.2 w/ Embedded Tomcat.

My application is a WAR file, not a .JAR file.  When I run in DEBUG, it never stops in my aspect even with hitting calls that should match the pointcuts, so that is how I figure it is not working...

My run script does this:

```
-javaagent:path/to/spring-instrument-xxx.jar -javaagent:path/to/aspectjweaver-1.2.8.jar
```

In Spring Boot, I load this AOP Config as an ApplicationInitializer, so it is in a parent ApplicationContext right away and should be there for all the rest of my embedded tomcat web application context thereafter.

```java
@EnableLoadTimeWeaving(aspectjWeaving=AspectJWeaving.ENABLED)
@Configuration
public class AopConfig {
    private Log log = LogFactory.getLog(AopConfig.class);

    public AopConfig() {
        log.info("Creating AopConfig");
    }

    @Bean
    public LoadTimeWeaver loadTimeWeaver() {
        log.info("Creating InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver");
        return new InstrumentationLoadTimeWeaver();
    }
}
```

My Aspect looks like this:

```java
package my.aop.profiler.MethodTimerAspect;

@Aspect
public class MethodTimerAspect {
    private static final String DELIMITER = "|";
    private static final String PROFILER = "profiler";
    private static final String DATE_FORMAT = "h:mm:ss";
    private static final Log LOG = LogFactory.getLog(PROFILER);

    public MethodTimerAspect() {}

    @Pointcut("execution (* my.web.*Controller.*(..))")
    protected void controllers() {}

    @Pointcut("execution (* my.services..*Facade.*(..))")
    protected void services() {}

    @Pointcut("execution (* my.services..*Exchange.*(..))")
    protected void data() {}

    /**
     * If profiling is enabled with trace, it will log the amount of time
     * spent in the method
     *
     * @param joinPoint
     * @return Object
     * @throws Throwable
     */
    @Around("controllers() || services() || data()")
    public Object doProfiling(ProceedingJoinPoint joinPoint) throws Throwable {
        // (...)
    }
}
```

My Embedded WAR's META-INF/aop.xml is this:

```xml
<!DOCTYPE aspectj PUBLIC "-//AspectJ//DTD//EN" "http://www.eclipse.org/aspectj/dtd/aspectj.dtd">
<aspectj>
    <weaver>
        <!-- only weave classes in our application-specific packages -->
        <include within="cdot.*"/>
    </weaver>
    <aspects>
        <!-- weave in just this aspect -->
        <aspect name="my.aop.profiler.MethodTimerAspect"/>
    </aspects>
</aspectj>
```

Answer (score 0):

Two ideas:

- Probably you want to change one of your pointcuts to also find subpackages (use `..` syntax instead of `.`):

  ```
  @Pointcut("execution (* my.web..*Controller.*(..))")
  ```
- The same applies to your *aop.xml*:

  ```
  <include within="cdot..*"/>
  ```

I assume that `my.web` was changed by you deliberately and actually reads `cdot.something`, because otherwise the pointcuts would not match.